# How to break inner loop but the loop still increment

Tags: c++, loops

```
for (int j=1; j<path.size(); j++) {
    //do something
    for (int z=0; z<path.size(); z++) {
        //do something
    }
    break;
}
```

The inner loop can loop from 0 until it hits the end of the path size, but the outer loop just keeps giving me `j=1` instead of doing the increment like inter loop does.

How can both loop do the increment at same time? I was trying to delete the `break;` but `z` loop through `path.size()`'s times.

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you want j and z to have the same value at all times?

Comment: j from 1 until hit the path.size(), z from 0 until hit the path.size() so j always 1 bigger than z

Comment: Right, but you have a ... Nevermind. Look at the answer that just popped up.

Comment: We've all been there @user4581301

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either. "j always 1 bigger than z": does it mean that you want, if path.size() is for example 5, something like: 1st iteration, j=1 and z=0; 2nd iteration, j=2 and z=1; 3rd iteration, j=3 and z=2; 4th iteration, j=4 and z=3, and then it stops because the condition isn't met? Then you need only one loop which increases both variables.

Comment: Should `inter loop` be `inner loop`?

Comment: @ckmss I recommend investing some time in learning about your IDE's debugger. If your IDE doesn't have a debugger, get a different IDE. Trust me you'll save a lot of time in the future. You would have spotted the bug almost instantly by stepping through the loop.

Comment: ^-- That too @user4581301 *agree*

Answer (score 2):

Try running this test program with and without the `break`

```
for (int j=1; j<5; j++) {
    printf("j=%d\n",j);
    for (int z=0; z<5; z++) {
        printf("z=%d\n",z);
    }
    break; // next time try to remove this break
}
```

and you might get enlightened.

If you want j and z to be counted up in parallel the you might want something like this

```
for (int j=1, z= 1; j<5; j++, z++) {
    printf("j=%d\n",j);
    printf("z=%d\n",z);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop executes completely for every iteration of the outer loop, that's why you see `z` going looping `path.size()` times. After this your loop stops due to  `break` so it won't iterate a second time over outer loop. So even if condition of outer loop is still true it won't even check it since you're breaking out of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int j = 1 ; j < path.size() ; j++){
   do something
   for (int z = 0 ; z < j ; z++){
       do something
   }
```

I think that's what you're looking for